# mmap from x86_64 on OSX

Tags: macos, mmap

I've tried this over and over and looked at disassembly of a small C version that works fine, but trying to allocate this small block of memory keeps returning '9' ? Can somebody see what I'm doing wrong, thanks.

```
movl    $0x0, %edi
movl    $0x4000, %esi           ## imm = 0x4000
movl    $0x3, %edx
movl    $0x1002, %ecx           ## imm = 0x1002
movq    $-0x1, %r8
movl    $0x0, %r9d
movl    $0x20000c5, %eax        ## imm = 0x20000C5
syscall
```

Regards

Chris

Comment: [Here's some help](https://filippo.io/making-system-calls-from-assembly-in-mac-os-x/) to get started sys calling from assembly on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I found the problem and it's that if using syscall you need to pass r10 rather than rcx ! From C the disassembly uses rcx because it doesn't call the syscall directly !

Hope this helps others.

Chris